# I can't get AWS S3 to serve media files on my Django/Heroku App

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

Been stuck on this for a while.  In my django site's admin page, I can upload a photo along with my blog post.  The photo will appear in my S3 bucket, but the photo won't render on the blog post.  Just a little photo icon.

Followed the simpleisbetterthancomplex tutorial, and have read through every relevant stackoverflow question I can find.  Can anyone see what it is that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Here is my settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '**********'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*********'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'matt-george-portfolio'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here is my bucket policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::964481289861:user/my-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::964481289861:user/my-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my user policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
                ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your last screen shot seems to be CORS policy. can you check(or add here) s3 bucket policy and the Iam user's or Iam roles's policy ?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I added the IAM policy.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.  The problem wasn't with my settings.py file, and it wasn't a an issue with IAM, CORS or bucket configuration.  I ended up following this tutorial and adding Cloudfront to my my bucket:
https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/serve-django-static-and-media-files-in-production

The solution to my issue was actually quite simple.  I was calling photos with the tag like this:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
       <div class="img"><img src="{{ post.image }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

But apparently, I overlooked the fact that you need to call images differently if they are coming from a bucket.  I added .url to the end of my tag, so now it looks like this:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
          <div class="img"><img src="{{ post.image.url }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now my django site serves media files without a problem.